# Multithreaded pyodbc connection

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, pyodbc

I am trying to use a pyodbc connection in multiple threads. I am receieving the following error: `Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')`. I also tried setting `MultipleActiveResultSets=yes;` and got the same results.

I really don't want to have to create a connection for every thread or query. I also don't want to use a lock to serialize queries from all threads.

I was first using the driver "SQL Server" and then moved to "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you opposed to having the connection wait to be freed, before using it again in a different thread?

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Yeah thats what I meant by not wanting to serialize threads with a lock. I might not have a choice though.

Comment: Yea I don't see what other choice you have. I don't know why your restrictions are what they are, but I'd opt for creating a new connection for each thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Joshua.

Comment: From the names of the ODBC drivers it sounds like you're doing this on Windows, and Windows ODBC enables connection pooling by default for SQL Server drivers, so opening a separate connection for each thread may not necessarily be as expensive as you fear.

Comment: @Gord that's correct. I think you are right about that. I did implement it that way and it appears to be working fine (so far). I have a "thread-safe" abstraction layer that handles the threads and connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question asks for suggestions and not really a strong answer, here's mine:

Firstly, I'd suggest creating a new connection for each thread created.

Or, if you're okay with killing what is currently executing, try cursor.cancel() before reusing your connection.

Also, after a quick search, I find multiple references to [Multiple Active Result Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-2017) related to this issue. If your database supports it, try adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your connection string.

I hope one of these suggestions helps you get where you need to be!

Answer (score 3):

According to ODBC-documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15, the keyword you should be using is `MARS_Connection=yes`. Using this with pyodbc does work and solves my dual-open-cursor -issue.

Using `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` does not work for two reasons: using incorrect keyword and using incorrect values, as in ODBC flags are not *true*/*false*, they are *yes*/*no*.